# Another way of Selecting data from mysql

Tags: java, try-catch

I done this code for selecting data from MySQL database and it is working. But I am wondering if it can be another way that is not involving `try` and `catch`

My code:

```
int i = 0;
    try {
        while (rs.next()) {
            int id = rs.getInt("id");
            int priority = rs.getInt("priority");
            String from = rs.getString("from");
            String to = rs.getString("to");
            String labelDb = rs.getString("label");
            String subject = rs.getString("subject");
            String message = rs.getString("message");


            data[i][0] = from;
            data[i][1] = id;
            data[i][2] = to;
            data[i][3] = labelDb;
            data[i][4] = subject;
            data[i][5] = message;
            i++;

        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a throws SQLException to the method header and remove the try catch block. for example:

```
public void runSQL() throws SQLException {

 //code in here
}
```

This would result in throwing the same exception to all the calling methods all the way back up to the main method.

Using SQLException is a better choice when throwing exceptions so its more clear what the problem actually is. You could just as well use Exception.

Answer (score 0):

U can make the method `throw` the `Exception`, but another one must `catch`it:

From:

```
private yourMethod ()
```

To

```
private yourMethod () throws Exception
```

But remember that means the method calling `yourMethod` must `catch` or also `throw` the `Exception`.